# Comapring two List<String> to extract the common items and put it in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

Im having two List items, how can I write a linq query to compare both and extract the common items.(Like List c, as shown below)

```
List<string> a = {a, b, c, d}
List<string> b = {c, d, e, f}

List<string> c = {c, d}
```

Comment: So many answers, and no one asked if the lists can have duplicates inside and if yes, that is the expected result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the LINQ `Intersect` method.

```
 var commonItems = a.Intersect(b);
```

variable `commonItems` will be a collection of common items from list `a` and list `b` , which is `["c","d"]`

Answer (score 4):

You can also call [`List.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx):

```
List<string> listA = {a, b, c, d}
List<string> listB = {c, d, e, f}

List<string> listC = listA.FindAll(elem => listB.Contains(elem));
```

Comment: How is FindAll different than where?

Comment: `FindAll` is a `List` method, `Where` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, `FindAll` returns a `List<T>`

Answer (score 3):

Because they're common to both lists, we can just grab the items from one list that are also in the other.  Like this:

```
List<string> c = a.Intersect(b)
                  .ToList();
```

This can be read as: "Select items from list a such that at least one item from list b has the same value."

Note that this only works for value types and reference types with a usable equality method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with a linq where query:

```
var c = a.Where(x => b.Contains(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Linq way:

```
   List<string> c = (from i in a
                     join j in b
                     on i equals j
                     select i).ToList();
```

Comment: And `ToString()` calls are for ...?

Comment: Not really a need, I fixed it. Thanks!